# Battery Drain Issue

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am using many threads in my app that are always running.These are used to send data to server periodically.There are called through services.The problem is that my app drains a lot of battery.I want to fix this.How??
I mean gmail etc dont drains that much of batterry.

Comment: If the threads send data periodically, they should only run periodically. Have a component whose job is to check whether there is data to send - if so, create a thread to send it and be done.

Comment: @Payal Is your service sending updated data to your server at every run or is it just used to sync data with server to check there is any updates available or not?

Comment: actually it sends updated data after every 5 mins. For that 5 mins thread has been put on sleep.

Comment: Use wakeful intentservice, to send data to server periodically instead of threads.
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful

Comment: This problem could be because of several things. So maybe this great talk can help you: [Google I/O 2009 - Coding for Life -- Battery Life, That Is](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUemfrKe65c)

Comment: @Payal : it's better if you implement your current code using AlarmManager and IntentService instead of Thread or timer

Answer (score 0):

Applications like Gmail are not requesting the server at frequent intervals, you may have to check the architecture of your solution, there are other mechanisms to do this you need:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to check [Googles Android Training on minimizing the battery usage](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html) and focus on ways effectively access the network and send files there.

There is also a [nice video presentation from Google's IO event](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/101/) that touches the topic (at around 1/3 of the video). It presents some code an is perhaps more easy to understand but less deep than the previously mentioned documentation